# iTextSharp IndexOutOfRange

Tags: c#, .net, itext

Keep getting IndexOutOfRangeException was unhandled exception.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var bdn = String.Format("{0}\\bdn.pdf", Application.StartupPath);
var reader = new PdfReader("bdn.pdf");
var numberOfPages = reader.NumberOfPages;
for (var currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <= numberOfPages; currentPageIndex++)
{
        sb.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, currentPageIndex));
}
```

Comment: What does this have to do with a console window?

Comment: You should start by looking at the API of that `PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage`. But you might try starting your index `currentPageIndex` at zero, and going until `currentPageIndex < numberOfPages`

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thank you for editing my title, Wasn't aware of that thanks. The Console Window is where i'd like to display the text. Honestly i can;t past that error so i have gone about Writing it to the PDF to the Console.

Comment: @VP. Tried it without success. Got a different exception this time however.     NullReferenceException

Comment: So you are _not_ trying to write to a console window. Your question is about the IndexOutOfRangeException. Once you have fixed that problem, you'll change your code to try to write to a console window.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Yes exactly.

Comment: @VP. Api offered no help.

Comment: Please provide a stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Yes, another rule on SO should be: *always* mention the version number of the tool you're using. If it's not the latest version, try the latest version. If it works for the latest version, don't post your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you're running an iTextSharp version greater than 5.1, which had a bug that exactly matches your problem:

- [iTextSharp v5 GetTextFromPage() throws IndexOutOfRangeException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8578793/itextsharp-v5-gettextfrompage-throws-indexoutofrangeexception)
- [Index was outside the bounds of the array while reading a .Pdf using iTextSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951408/index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-while-reading-a-pdf-using-itextsharp)

Just tested with 5.5.4.0 (latest version), using this code, which works:

```
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
// substitute 'pdfPath' with path to YOUR PDF
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfPath);
    int pageNumber = 1;
    while (pageNumber <= reader.NumberOfPages) {
      sb.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageNumber));
      ++pageNumber;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, another rule on SO should be: *always* mention the version number of the tool you're using. If it's not the latest version, try the latest version. If it works for the latest version, don't post your question.

Comment: @kuujinbo Thank you very much. Solved the problem. Well sort off. I can now display a pdf, Just not the on i want. That however i will figure out on my own. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies within your `for loop`:

```
for (var currentPageIndex = 1; currentPageIndex <= numberOfPages; currentPageIndex++)
{
    PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, currentPageIndex);
}
```

There are a couple of problems with the above code:

**Problem #1**

I don't know your reasons for starting at `index 1`, rather than `index 0`, since collections and arrays in `C#` start at `index 0`... perhaps you're trying to skip the first page.  If you do start at `index 1`, understand that you're starting the count on the second page.  This brings me to the second problem...

**Problem #2**

```
currentPageIndex <= numberOfPages
```

As an example, if `currentPageIndex` is `3` and `numberOfPages` is `3`, this expression would evaluate to `true`, allowing the code within the block to execute.  However, `numberOfPages` indicates the length/count of the array/collection.  Thus, the last valid index for the length of `3`, would be `index 2`.

You must change it to:

```
currentPageIndex < numberOfPages
```

... since `currentPageIndex` must remain less than the total number pages.  Otherwise, it will be out of bounds.

I would also recommend learning how to debug, so that you may either step through your code or check the values at the time the exception gets thrown.

Comment: I now get a different exception NullReferenceException. I am not sure if this is better or worse...

Comment: @T0rchic That tells us nothing.  It could be that the file you're loading does not exist or you've provided a wrong path.  Step through your code using the debugger.  Besides, I'm not even sure if that's all of your code that you're showing us... since `sb` doesn't do anything.

Comment: i use to do this, Not sure why i didnt incorporate this in the beginning. sb.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, currentPageIndex)